# My browser keeps throwing an error saying "Uncaught TypeError: n.charAt is not a function"

Tags: javascript, html

I keep getting the same error:

> Uncaught TypeError: n.charAt is not a function

even though `charAt()` is a function.

First I used

```
var n = document.getElementById('D').charAt(-1);
document.getElementById('D').innerHTML = n + 1;
```

Then it threw the error, then I tried

```
var n = document.getElementById('D');
var dn = n.charAt(-1);
document.getElementById('D').innerHTML = dn + 1;
```

But it *still* threw the error. I want to change a `<span>` element from "Deaths: 0" to "Deaths: 1".

Comment: because an html element does not have charAt. You are not looking at the text, but the element itself.

Comment: Look into documentation for `charAt`

Comment: [`charAt` is a function on a string instance](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/charAt).

Comment: `getElementById` returns the element. You need to `getElementById('D').innerHTML.charAt()` or `textContent.charAt()`

Comment: @_Whoever posted the comment that says "getElementById returns the element. You need to getElementById('D').innerHTML.charAt() or textContent.charAt()"_ Now I'm getting the error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'charAt' of undefined".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An element has no function "charAt". You should do:

```
var n = document.getElementById('D').innerHTML.charAt(-1);
```

Full code, that should work:

```
var n = document.getElementById('D');
n.innerHTML = parseInt(n.innerHTML) + 1;
```

Edit:

```
var n       = document.getElementById('D');
var text    = n.innerHTML;
var numb    = parseInt(text.split(':')[1].trim())  + 1
n.innerHTML = "Deaths: " + numb
```

Comment: Now it says "NaN".

Comment: Because, you need nothing else than an inital 0 inside your element. NaN means not a number. If you would like to write text too into your element, please provide an example.

Comment: Look at the question again, I edited it.